# Create new user is not notified by email

Tags: dotnetnuke

When I create a new user in DNN, The newly created users are not notified by email from the system after they have been created. There is no difference between "tick" in "Notify" or not set (see the image below)

[image]

How I can setup the system in order to get user got notified by email after they have been created (in this case to email aldho_ah@yahoo.com)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an SMTP server to send email.  Go to `Host > Host Settings > Advanced Settings > SMTP Server Settings`, and you can see what information the portal needs:

[image: DNN's SMTP Server Settings]

The portal will send emails from the email address of the site's administrator, which is defined at `Admin > Site Settings > Advanced Settings > Security Settings`.  This means that the SMTP server needs to have permission to send from that email address.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However the solution you are provide only send email to the admin, not the "new regitered user". Am I correct?